# Marketing cloud push notification not visible on Android

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush-android

I've implemented Marketing Cloud Mobile Push, we have multiple SDKs however I'm letting Marketing cloud handle tokens, all I'm doing is using a custom GCMListenerService to process my push if its from Marketing Cloud.  The app receives the push notifications however its not displayed.

```
marketingCloudSdk.getNotificationManager().areNotificationsEnabled()
```

is true

```
marketingCloudSdk.getPushMessageManager().isPushEnabled() is also true
```

and this returns true as well

```
boolean isHandled = marketingCloudSdk.getPushMessageManager().handlePushMessage(bundle);
```

and so is the above.

This is my on messageReceived in the service

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String s, final Bundle extras) {
    track.sendNoInteraction(AnalyticsView.notificationReceived, TrackingAction.AnalyticsAction.alertNotificationReceived, TrackingPreferences.DEFAULT_EVENT_LABEL);
    SalesForceNotificationHandler notificationHandler = new DefaultSalesForceNotificationHandler(getApplicationContext(), extras);
    if (notificationHandler.canHandle()) {
        notificationHandler.handle();
        return;
    }
    handleAppPushNotification(extras);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you've wrapped the interactions with the SDK to handle the push inside on this `DefaultSalesForceNotification` class.  What is the code you have  in that class?  Are you providing an implementation of the NotificationBuilder override when initializing the SDK?  Do you see other notifications getting displayed?

Comment: Hey Seth, I identified the issue, it was only on Oreo and above, if I didn't specify a NotificationChannel the notification would fail on Oreo devices, by specifying a channel its now working fine. Thanks.

Comment: What version of the Marketing Cloud SDK are you using?  There is suppose to be a check in the SDK, after v5.2.0, that makes sure that the notification channel is setup correctly when your project is targeting Android API >=26.  Did you provide a channel name during init or did you  opt to use the notification channel override interface?